# Trouble running an applet made in Eclipse in a browser

Tags: java, eclipse, browser, jar, applet

I have made a Java applet game in Eclipse which has many classes and media associated with it. I have now been trying to finally test the game in a browser but I am having a hell of a hard time getting it to work.

I have exported a .jar file (a non-runnable, could that be a problem?) and tried many different ways of loading the applet. I have read over the materials on the oracle website as well.

My first two basic questions are:

1. My applet does not have a `static void main(String args[]){` line because I was under the impression that for applets you use a `init()` and `start()` method. Could this be the problem? 
   if not, my class which contains the init and start and the other basic methods is called `Start.class` and is located in a `bin/` directory. Am I able to edit the manifest which is included in the .jar exported from eclipse and but this `Start.class` as the main class using `Main-Class: Game.Start`?
2. Another very basic question also when it comes to directories in java or specifically in .jar archives, are folders in a path names always separated by a `.`? or do `/`'s work too?

My project name is simply Game, I have a `src` folder with .java files and a `bin` folder with .class how do I direct the manifest to the `bin/start.class` file?

Sorry this has been rather frustrating especially because I really want to be able to share this applet. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Q: Are you running this applet in a web browser (or appletviewer)?  If not, it won't work.

Comment: Check your java console for errors and post them.

Comment: @paulsm4: check the title of his question. He states there that he's running the applet in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) My applet does not have a `static void main (args[]){` line because I was under the impression that for applets you use a `init()` and `start()` method. Could this be the problem?

No, this is not a problem, as Applets and JApplets do not use main methods to run. Note that some may have main methods that may be used to allow the coder to test the code in a non-applet environment, but when run as an applet, the main methods are ignored.

> 2) Another very basic question also when it comes to directories in Java or specifically in .jar archives, are folders in a path names always separated by a "."? or do "/"'s work too?

the directeries in jar files use "/". Please check that you are not trying to use resources as *Files* since jar files do not hold files (but rather resources).

> My project name is simply Game, I have a src folder with .java files and a bin folder with .class how do I direct the manifest to the bin/start.class file?

Consider showing the structure of your jar file and also a small test html file where you try to run the applet.

Comment: The problem seems to be that the java console can't find my start.class. Could this be a problem solved with the manifest? Or a .jnlp file?

Comment: @user1477262: this can all usually be easily fixed with proper HTML code. Again, please show us a small HTML file that tries to load your applet, and also show the structure of your applet, perhaps an image from Eclipse.

Comment: Ai know that the basic applet calling html takes a class and the archive as parameters - is that class that is being called the class with my init() method? Since the start.class is archived in my .jar file is it calling it from the .jar file? Or do I need a non-archived version of that class? If I am in a folder which contains my src folder and bin folder aswell as my .jar could I call the "bin/start.class" and archive = "whatever.jar" in the <applet> code? Does the manifest in the archive need to be altered?

Comment: Sorry - I am not at home at the moment - I will post this evening - thanks for your help.

Comment: 'Maybe' to both questions.  Modern applets and JWS apps. can specify the main class and dependent Jars in the manifest of the main Jar.  OTOH the same basic constraints apply to them - it all comes down to the paths of the resources being in the places that the JRE expects them to be.  That is better sorted in HTML than a manifest (if only for the fact that you do not need to rebuild the Jar for each test).  Please fill in the information that @HFOE suggested.  We cannot help you sort it, short of knowing the details of the structure.

Comment: Thanks again - I will post pictures and info later this eve

Comment: Sorry I worked late last night and didnt have time. I have some pictures now:

Comment: http://s18.postimage.org/gmi2mfqzt/Eclipse.jpg

This is my eclipse project screen. As you can see there are many classes and two other directories. One holds .png images and the other .au audio clips.

http://s9.postimage.org/a49o1ql0f/folder.jpg

This is the project folder. I have my Runna.jar (again exported as a non-runnable jar) and my html file. 

So I have the following simple html (I have also tried jnlp and other ways) but I figure this most basic code should work:

<body>
    <applet code = 'bin/start.class' 
    archive = 'Runna.jar', 
    width = 800, 
    height = 600 />
</body>

Comment: sorry about the formatting above! Also I have tried using an applet code = "bin/start" too

Comment: I should add that its actually "Start"

Comment: Lastly, Please let me know any other information you need to help me with this situation.

Answer (score 1):

> Start.class and is located in a bin/ directory

I agree with Hovercratft about a missing main (not missing), about runnable jar (not necessary).

One problem which might exists is the exact location of files and naming of classes.

If your class name is bin.Start, because you defined a package bin (very uncommon), you need to put the bin directory into the jar.

If you didn't declare a package, you don't have a directory to put into the jar. Maybe eclipse handles this for you automatically.

To test your applet, you need a html file, and start the html file in the appletviewer. If this works, you test it in the browser. Else verify that you can start foreign applets in your browser, to make sure it is installed in the correct way.

Since you show a sloppy habit in the question of cases: Start.class or start.class: This is significant for Java. Use initial uppercase names everywhere.

Comment: "One problem which might exists is the exact location of files and naming of classes." -- Yep, which is why he needs to show us this information. 1+

Comment: Sorry it is definitely Start.class

Comment: My biggest problem it seems is that I am confused by the actual jar archive. The class I want to begin with is called Start.class. I have my jar which has all the class files and resources in it. Now I am not sure what I need to call exactly and there seems to be many ways of running the applet based on the applet deployment literature on the oracle site. Is the "applet code = "" " code calling the class from the archive? or the non-archived version? My browser seems to be set up fine I can view the example applets on the oracle tutorial pages.

Comment: @user1477262: If your applet works in Eclipse (can you decide whether it is run from the JAR or maybe from a bin folder? Does eclipse use a HTML-file?), and the browser works with the demo applets from oracle, it must be the way you invoke the applet in the html file, or the deployment of the jar, or the build of the jar. I would expect a) or b), not so much c). View the source of the oracle demo html, and do as they do. Tell us the details how you test your applet in your question: Do you upload html and jar to the net, or do you call it locally? Where do you store which? How are they named?

Comment: @user1477262: We're missing entirely what the concrete symptoms of `Trouble running an applet ... in a browser` is. Browser crash, a message `applet not found`, what else? Be specific!